# Issues filtering some events in splunk on an indexer

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm working with Splunk version 5.0.1.
I want to filter the logs being indexed.

I've added these lines to `transforms.conf` file:

```
[setparsing]
REGEX = log: myCompany|\[CRIT\]|\[ERR\]
DEST_KEY = queue
FORMAT = indexQueue
```

So what I want is to index all the log entries that have one of these strings.
But for some reason only logs with these entries are indexed:

```
log: myCompany
```

while log entries with the string `"[CRIT]" or "[ERR]"` aren't indexed.

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the regex, because I checked many Perl examples. And that's how we write a regex for log: myCompany or `[CRIT] or [ERR]`.

Comment: Do you need quotes around the regex?

Comment: ? i'm not sure i understand the question...

Comment: Can you show a complete sample log that is not being selected? Also, maybe you want to try the splunk `OR` keyword instead of `|`.